# Remove white space on HTML/CSS banner?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have tried every kind of CSS trick I know to remove this white space including cell-padding, margins, padding ect ect.

Any idea how to remove this white space below the "sign up" on this banner?

http://oil.wpengine.com/

[image]

Comment: For first, in <div id="frame"> there's 10px padding to top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to this `<img>` in the row *below* the row with the "sign up" `<img>`. I did it inline here, but you'll probably want a class.

```
<img src="images/OFC_Home_Header_15.png" width="75" height="10" style="vertical-align: top">
```

> [image]

Comment: This didn't fix it in my browser, (Firefox 19)

Comment: @DylanCross Sure you did the right image? Works fine on FF19 for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slicing problem. Fix this image

```
<img width="75" height="10" alt="" src="images/OFC_Home_Header_15.png">
```

This **solves** the problem:

```
<img width="75" height="10" alt="" src="images/OFC_Home_Header_15.png" style="margin-top:-2px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    <img src="images/OFC_Home_Header_15.png" width="75" height="10" alt="" 
style="margin-top: -3px;"/>
```